# Converting a Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe converts timestamp to object

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark (v1.6.3) dataframe that I convert to a Pandas dataframe (Python v2.7.12). There are 2 timestamp columns, but one of them is converted to `datetime64` while the other one is converted to `object`. Any idea on what's going on?

```
df.printSchema()
```

This results in the following.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gps_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

```
df.take(1)
```

Results in the following.

```
[Row(id=u'000000', gps_id=860, start_date=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 29, 0, 0), end_date=datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 6, 0, 0))]
```

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf.dtypes
```

```
id                          object
gps_id                       int32
start_date           datetime64[ns]
end_date                     object
dtype: object
```

The interesting thing is if I type `pdf.head(1)` then I see the following. Note how the `start_date` does not have the `HH:mm:ss` appended.

```
id     gps_id   start_date           end_date
000000 860      2017-09-29           2018-09-06 00:00:00
```

The SQL to generate the dataset is very simple and looks like the following.

```
select
 id,
 gps_id,
 cast(start_date as timestamp) as start_date,
 cast(end_date as timestamp) as end_date
from gps_tbl
```

Comment: are there null values for end_date at all?

Comment: @cowbert There are no null values.

Comment: well, if the end_date still duck types to a datetime type, you should be fine (check with `isinstance` or look for methods in `dir()`).  ([this old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/lxhnFtuzvWQ) suggests back in the day numpy/pd datetimes used to be primarily generic objects at one point).

Comment: @cowbert Thanks. The `null` was the hint; there were no `null` values but there were sentinel values `9999-12-31` that was making the conversion bad.

Comment: 9999-12-31 should be a valid python datetime though...https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.MAXYEAR